# BufferedImage comparing image with itself throws ArrayOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I compare BufferedImage objects in Java. I got the image from a set and compare it with all of the images in the same set. However, it gives causes this strange error comparing the image with itself and everything works well for the other images. Here's the code:

```
private boolean diagonalCompare() {
    for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < w && j < h; i++, j++) {
        if(bimg1.getRGB(i, j) != bimg2.getRGB(i, j)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    for(int i = w, j = 0; i > -1 && j < h; i--, j++) {
//-----------THIS IS THE LINE CAUSES THE ERROR---------------------------------\\
        if(bimg1.getRGB(i, j) != bimg2.getRGB(i, j)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here's the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Coordinate out of bounds!
at sun.awt.image.ByteInterleavedRaster.getDataElements(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getRGB(Unknown Source)
at com.oy.duplicator.SimpleComparator.diagonalCompare(SimpleComparator.java:144)
at com.oy.duplicator.SimpleComparator.compareBufferedImage(SimpleComparator.java:78)
at com.oy.duplicator.SimpleComparator.compare(SimpleComparator.java:44)
at com.oy.duplicator.Main.main(Main.java:78)
```

`ArrayOutOfBoundsException`? Why is that? Maybe it's something caused by reading the same file, but it works in the first `for-loop`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is because in all your other images you never get to execute the second for-loop.

The second for loop should be:

```
for(int i = w - 1, j = 0; i > -1 && j < h; i--, j++) {
```

(`w - 1` instead of `w`)

Otherwise you are starting your comparison with the coordinate `(w, 0)` and as coordinates are going to be only valid from `0` to `w - 1`, that's why you're getting the exception.